# sublimetext2 build appears blank

Tags: python, build, sublimetext2

When a hit ctrl + b with a python script open I get the "building" message and then nothing but blank space.

This is the script, and it runs perfectly on IDLE.

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Hello, " + name + "!")
```

Is there any configuration I need to do to get this working?

I'm running python 3.2 and Sublime Text 2 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm not sure that Sublime's build command can handle things like `input`; I don't think it's identical to running the program.  I've had lots of problems with it before.

Comment: Is your file extension correct (.py)? Did you add python to your path variable? Try to use the F7 key instead of ctrl + b, this will exectue the default builder for the file extension.

Comment: Yes, the file extension is ok. Also I tried using F7 but got the same result. How do I add python to my path variable?

Comment: If testing out a python code block in a text editor is your intention, I'd suggest you to use NP++ for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime's default build command does not run interactively.  When I use it with your script, I see "What's your name?", and then blank.  You might check out the answers to the question "[Running python interactively from within sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14080041/1309332)."