# Running Python interactively from within Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I have looked at all the answers on this forum but I'm missing something.
I want to be able to hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> while editing a Python file "myfile.py" in Sublime Text 2.

This should open up a Python shell that loads my file and returns me to the interactive prompt  so the namespace in my Python script is available.

Setting the `-i` option in the build setting still closes the interpreter (see below)

```
> 81
> >>>  [Finished in 0.1s]
```

I downloaded **sublimeREPL** but I'm not sure how to set the `-i` option.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 11):

ok, thanks to sneawo for the hints! Here's my first cut at doing this.

Step 1. Create a plugin pydev, (from Tools->New Plugin) which creates a command 'pydev'

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class PydevCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command('set_layout', {"cols":[0.0, 1.0], "rows":[0.0, 0.5, 1.0], "cells":[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2]]})
        self.window.run_command('repl_open',{"type": "subprocess",
                                             "encoding": "utf8",
                                             "cmd": ["python2.7", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
                                             "cwd": "$file_path",
                                             "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                             "external_id": "python2.7"
                                             })
        self.window.run_command('move_to_group', { "group": 1 })
```

Step 2. Create a new key binding in the Preferences->Key-Bindings-user

> `{"keys": ["f5"], "command": "pydev"}`

Now pressing <kbd>f5</kbd> (on the Mac it will be <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> by default) does the trick-it will start the python interpreter in a repl tab, set the layout to two-window horizontal and move the repl tab to the lower window.

This is pretty basic in that it doesn't check to see what the current layout is and simply sets the layout to 2-horizontal. Will probably spruce up the code to do some checking and simply add a horizontal window to the existing layout. Also would be good to remove the horizontal buffer when the repl tab is closed.

Comment: this does not work for windows, getting error `system cannot find the file specified`. Can you please tip what should be changed?

Comment: A note: this may break when trying to access dictionaries. Adding `"extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}` to the command arguments fixes this issue.

Comment: Just wonder if it's possible like with `REPL:R` to send stuff from a script to an already existing REPL console.

Answer (score 7):

Try to update your user keybindings:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+shift+r"], "command": "repl_open", 
                 "caption": "Python",
                 "mnemonic": "p",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python"
                    } 
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I needed!! Is it possible to open the repl terminal as a split window horizontally or as a an external window?

Comment: I think it's possible with macro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646552/is-it-possible-to-chain-key-binding-commands-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense as a build rule?

Comment: Great! Is it possible to run the file in a REPL window already open ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is much more simple than your approach.
Just define a new build "profile" (Build system), in it you capture exactly the default Python build, except changing option `-u` to `-ui`

> `{
>   "cmd": ["C:\\python33\\python.exe", "-ui", "$file"],
>       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
>       "selector": "source.python"
>   }`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a quick edit to the answer by @user1936097.

I copied the idea but wanted to instead load IPython (the code as is works fine to load standard Python). I replaced...

```
self.window.run_command('repl_open',{"type": "subprocess",
                                             "encoding": "utf8",
                                             "cmd": ["python2.7", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
                                             "cwd": "$file_path",
                                             "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                             "external_id": "python2.7"
                                             })
```

with...

```
self.window.run_command('repl_open', {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "autocomplete_server": true,
                    "cmd": ["python","-u","${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python",
                    "extend_env": {
                        "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                        "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"}
                    })
```

But it didn't work.

The line `"autocomplete_server": true` seemed to be the problem. If I removed it, the code ran, but IPython opened the closed. If I left it, nothing happened.

I finally borrowed a command found in the file `/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Default.sublime-commands` and came up with...

```
self.window.run_command('run_existing_window_command', {
                        "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
                    })
```

This made the final plugin code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class PydevCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command('set_layout', {"cols":[0.0, 1.0], "rows":[0.0, 0.5, 1.0], "cells":[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2]]})
        self.window.run_command('run_existing_window_command', {
                        "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
                    })
        self.window.run_command('move_to_group', { "group": 1 })
```

Assign this to a keybind as shown in the original post and you will now load IPython instead of standard Python!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an easy way just creating a new build system.

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python33\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Then save the build system as Python3 or Python27 and select it as default.

Comment: This looks exactly like the default build rule.  Do you think that this does something different from the default build rule?