# Running a .py file from Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Hi everyone I'm new to programming.

I am learning Python and I want to use Sublime Text as an IDE.

I've searched and found that it is impossible to run python code from sublime text2 without having the "eofError".

Now, I want to know if it was possible to launch the .py via a keyboard shortcut directly from sublime text, instead of saving it, and then returning to windows explorer and then double clicking on it.

I want it to open in a windows like this : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/16/1366399189-nnnnn.png

Thanks.

---

I just found a solution here that does basically the same job as the "F5" key in IDLE.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen that post. It doesn't really answer my question since what I want to do is to create a shortcut that permits me to launch the *.py file like when doing in cmd "c:\windows\py.exe file" What I want to do is that same exact thing, but directly from sublime text.

Comment: But it clearly mentions that what you're looking for is not possible in sublimetext2, as it doesn't supports input from STDIN.

Comment: Sorry I don't even know what is STDIN. As for your link, can you please tell me how to execute the script in sublimerepl's console tab? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Great editor. Here is a resource for creating macros in Sublime Text 2:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-banish-repetitive-tasks-with-sublime-text-2-macros/

This previous post might also have what you are looking for:

[Running Python interactively from within Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080041/running-python-interactively-from-within-sublime-text-2)

Comment: I don't think the question is related to macros.

Comment: The asker wants a way to fire off a command based on a keystroke. The link I Posted explains how to set macros to key bindings in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: But this doesn't answers OP's question, his question is not about learning Macros. He wants to get input from STDIN which is AFAIK is not supported by sublimetext2.